# Save value in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with sub forms.
I have `submit` button for outer form but in the same time and for inner. The outer form works fine, it saves all data. but i can't get values from inner form clicking on

```js
   <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit Inner
        </Button>
   </Form.Item>
```

Clicking on that i want to get values inside inner component in:

```js
const onFinish = v => {
    console.log("inner", v);
  };
```

The subform code:

```js
 <Form.List onFinish={onFinish} name={[props.fieldKey, "inner"]}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <div>
                  <Form.Item
                    // name={"aar"}
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "innerName"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "innerName"]}
                    key={index}
                    noStyle
                  >
                    <Input
                      placeholder="passenger name"
                      style={{ width: "60%" }}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                      Submit Inner
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </div>
              ))}

              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => {
                  add();
                }}
                style={{ width: "60%" }}
              >
                <PlusOutlined /> Add field
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
```

But when i click on this i get values in the outer form.

Question: How to get values from inner form  clicking on `Submit Inner` button?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/SubForm.js

now i get:
[image]

expected result:
[image]

Comment: There's not enough code to understand what's going on, to provide an accurate answer

Comment: @vsync, i added the code in the question, could you help?

Comment: Please explain your terminology of *"save value"*. Save in what way? where? is this even relevant to the question? Seems like the title is unrelated to your actual issue

Comment: @vsync,  clicking on the `Submit Inner` button i want to save data  just from the sub form just. Now when i click i get: names: Array[1]
0: Object
inner: Array[1]
0: Object
innerName: "Inner Data"
outer: "Outter data", but i want to get just `inner` array

Comment: @vsync, i added 2 images in the question, there is what i get now and what i expect clicking on the button. Please tell me if my expectation is clear. Thanks

Comment: what is "inner form"? you cannot have form inside a form, you can only have 1 form and as many fields as you want. Anyway, I don't understand what is this "saving" thing you keep mentioning, why is this even relevant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217312/discussion-between-asking-and-vsync).

Comment: `wonderful ives` LOL. What a nice random generated slug for codesandbox.

Comment: @vsync, did you check the sandbox?

Comment: in HTML there can only be **one** form without inner forms/submits, there is no such concept as *"inner submit"*.. not sure even multiple button would submit the same form. perhaps you need to manually trigger a form "submit" event for those other buttons, with `onClick`. again, this is wrong-approach.